# .NET Conditionally use a .NET library if installed

Tags: c#, sql, .net, vb.net, t-sql

My question is fairly simple.  I am wanting to add a new section to my project that will utilize the SMO .NET Libraries (SQL Server Management Object).  I believe these are only installed if SQL Management Studio is installed on the computer.  Is it possible for me to the write code for execution only if the libraries are installed on the computer that runs my program?  Meaning if it's not installed, then they can use all the other features of the program.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713979(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap the entry function calls that use those assemblies in a try-catch block for `FileNotFoundException`.

When you run the code, it will try to load the DLL, and if it's not there, it will throw a FileNotFound, which you can catch and disable the UI.